# Display the legend inside the graph when wrapping with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, facet, facet-wrap

How can I do...

[image: legend is in a spare corner of a small multiple]

... instead of the default ...

[image]

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use the `diamonds` data set for this. You could use the `theme(legend.position=` to do it:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, fill = ..density..)) +
  xlim(0, 2) + stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE) + theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ color) + theme(legend.position=c(.8,.15))
```

Output:

[image]

Essentially, `theme(legend.position=c(.8,.15))` takes two values that range from 0 to 1, one for the x-axis and one for the y-axis. 0 means place the legend at the beginning of the axis whereas 1 means at the end of the axis.

You can have a look at the [cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/) if you like where there are more examples.

Also as per @Roland 's comment using the following with `legend.justification` will probably position it even better:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, fill = ..density..)) +
  xlim(0, 2) + stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE) + theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ color) + theme(legend.position = c(1, 0), legend.justification = c(1, 0))
```

Comment: Possibly also adjust the `legend.justification`, i.e., `theme(legend.position = c(1, 0), legend.justification = c(1, 0))`.

Comment: Yeah thanks @Roland . I ll add the link to the cookbook where it also mentions about the `legend.justification` argument.

Comment: I guess there is no other way than tweaking those 4 parameters?

Comment: Not that I know of @Arthur . You ll always need to tweak some parameters in order to do what you want. `theme(legend.position = c(1, 0), legend.justification = c(1, 0))` will always place it in the bottom right corner.

Comment: It's just that it is often better to have the legend inside the plot instead of outside, when it does not override the content. So when there is some spare space, this could be built in, I guess...

Comment: Yep it can be coded in a function according to the number of facets you have.